# How to divide by negative numbers?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic

How to divide by negative numbers? Like what is the quotient and remainder when 24 is divided by $-5$ or $-24$ is divided by $5$?

Comment: The "definition" for (integer) division is $ \ \frac{a}{b} \ = \ q  \ + \ \frac{r}{b} \ $ , with $ \ b  \ > \ 0 \ $ , $ \ q \ $ being the (integer) quotient and $ \ r \ \ge \ 0 \ $ being the remainder.  So $ \ \frac{-24}{5} \ $ (which is the same value as $ \ \frac{24}{-5} \ $ ) equals $ \ \frac{-25}{5} \ + \ \frac{1}{5} \ = \ -5 \ + \ \frac{1}{5} \ $ , that is, the quotient is  -5  and the remainder is 1 .  This agrees with the decimal value $ \ -4.8 \ $ .  [This is a common, but reasonable question, since school arithmetic doesn't generally discuss how to work with _negative_ numbers.]

Comment: By the way, I observe that someone gave a -1 tip to the question. Is it a common rule to someone gives a negative tip if the question is of lower level than his own level of knowledge, or to someone gives a positive tip if the question is of higher level than his own level of knowledge ? (With this question, I expect negative tips for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Division Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) states that given a pair of integers $a$ and $b$, with $b \neq 0$, there exist integers $q$ and $r$, with $0 \leq r < |b|$ such that $a = q|b| + r$.

When we divide $24$ by $5$, $q = 4$ and $r = 4$ since $24 = 4 \cdot 5 + 4$.

Since $4 \cdot 5 = (-4)(-5)$, $24 = (-4)(-5) + 4$.

The quotient of $-24$ and $5$ takes a little more thought.

Note that $-24 = -4 \cdot 5 - 4$.  Our remainder is negative, but we want $0 \leq r < 5$.  Observe that -4 = -5 + 1. Hence,
\begin{align*}
-24 & = -4 \cdot 5 - 4\\
    & = -4 \cdot 5 - 5 + 1\\
    & = (-4 - 1)5 + 1\\
    & = -5 \cdot 5 + 1
\end{align*}
In practice, the following method is more efficient.  Note that $-25$ is the largest multiple of $5$ that is less than $-24$ and $-24 - (-25) = 1$.  Since $-25 = -5 \cdot 5$, we obtain 
$$-24 = -25 + 1 = -5 \cdot 5 + 1$$